# Using Twilio I want to add a third party into a call using an iOS Device

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I'm using Twilio in an iOS app using the TwilioClient library in Swift. The app I've built can connect from user A's device to user B's device or to an outside phone number. This is working fine. What I need to do now is to bring a third party into the call, either a third iOS device (user C) or an additional outside line.

I understand that I will need to use the Conference capability to do this, but I'm not finding examples of how to do this with the TwilioClient library for iOS. Currently my TwiML server is the Python quick start server (which has been fine for two-party calls).

What I'm unclear on is:

1. Using the TwilioClient device.connect(...) call how do I connect User A & User B into a conference room in the first place?
2. Once I have A & B in the conference call, how, using TwilioClient, do I bring in party C? I've connected with device.connect(...) which hides all of the REST API code from me.
3. Since I don't know at the beginning of the call if I'll need the third party is there a way to start off with a direct connect then add all parties to a conference call once we decide we need to add User C?

Thanks,
KeithB

Answer (score 2):

Below is an answer on how to solve question 1 in my OP.

When you use the iOS call device.connect(...) it calls the TwiML server /call URL (in my case a Python server), which returns "TwiML" ([Twilio Markup Language](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml)). The basic pattern is to call a destination directly. To do this the TwiML server uses the passed parameters To: and From: and constructs a TwiML "Dial" string that is returned. This causes Twilio to dial the To: number using the From: number as a callerid.

In order to have both parties put into a conference it is a two step process. First you modify your TwiML code to tell Twilio to put the Caller into the conference room. Second, you use the REST API at the TwiML server to have Twilio call out to the To: caller and put them in the conference room.

This requires several changes. First you must pass in the conference room name from the [device.connect(...)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/tcconnection) call in your iOS app.

```
connection = device?.connect(["To": "+1234567890", "Conference": "MyConference"], delegate: delegate)
```

Then you have to modify the /call route in the Python server to return TwiML for a conference room AND make the outbound REST call.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

@app.route('/call', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def call():
  account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
  auth_token = os.environ.get("AUTH_TOKEN", AUTH_TOKEN)
  from_value = request.values.get('From')
  to = request.values.get('To')
  conf_room = request.values.get('Conference')
  callsid_value = request.values.get('CallSid')

  # This section creates the TwiML code that will be returned 
  # This causes the caller to be placed in a conference room
  # Note: endConferenceOnExit=true ends conference when call originator exits
  conf_response = twilio.twiml.Response()
  conf_response.dial(callerId=from_value).conference(conf_room, endConferenceOnExit="true")

  # This section makes the REST call out to the To: number
  client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
  call = client.calls.create(url="www.YourPythonServer" + "/getconf?Conference=" + conf_room,
                           to=to,
                           from_=from_value,
                           method="POST",
                           status_callback="www.YourPythonServer" + "/callback?init_callsid=" + callsid_value,
                           status_callback_method="POST",
                           status_events=["completed"])
return str(conf_response)
```

When we call client.calls.create(...) it causes Twilio to then call the URL "www.yourpythonserver/getconf..." to get the TwiML it uses to know how to execute the outgoing call.

```
@app.route('/getconf', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def getconf():
  resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
  conf_room = request.values.get('Conference')

  resp.dial().conference(conf_room)
  return str(resp)
```

You'll notice up above we also have a parameter "status_callback". This is used to let us know the To: caller's status. In this case we request 'complete' but we may also get "no-answer", "busy" & "failed". If we don't do this and the call is unsuccessful then the caller will just sit in an empty conference room w/o knowing the outgoing call was unsuccessful. This requires yet another route in our Python server.

```
@app.route('/callback', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def callback():

  account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
  auth_token = os.environ.get("AUTH_TOKEN", AUTH_TOKEN)
  init_callsid = request.values.get('init_callsid')
  callback_status = request.values.get('CallStatus')

  # Check to see what status was passed in. Note that "completed" is 
  # passed after a successful call and the To: party hangs up or drops.
  # You can implement any behavior you want here, but this code 
  # simply hangs up the originating caller. This might not be appropriate
  # if there are still other parties in the call.
  if callback_status == 'completed' or callback_status == "no-answer" or callback_status == 'busy' or callback_status == 'failed':
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    call = client.calls.hangup(init_callsid)

  return str("")
```

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks for this awesome update. Awesome to see you figured it out and came back here to share it! Can I send you a shirt to say thanks? Email mspeir@twilio.com. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an answer to question #2 in my OP.

After step #1 we have a conference room named 'MyConference' with parties 1 & 2 (From & To). Now we would like to add a third party to the conference and trigger that action from our iPhone.

What we need to do is create a new Route in our python server and call that route directly from our iOS code.

The code in the python server will look something like this:

```
@app.route('/add_to_conference', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def add_to_conference():
  account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
  auth_token = os.environ.get("AUTH_TOKEN", AUTH_TOKEN)
  from_value = request.values.get('From')
  to = request.values.get('To')
  conf_room = request.values.get('Conference')

  client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
  call = client.calls.create(url="www.YourPythonServer" + "/getconf?Conference=" + conf_room,
                           to=to,
                           from_=from_value,
                           method="POST",
                           status_callback="www.YourPythonServer" + "/callback?Conference=" + conf_room,
                           status_callback_method="POST",
                           if_machine = "Hangup",
                           status_events=["completed"]
                           )

return str("True")
```

The code above will make a REST call that will cause Twilio to make an outgoing call to the "To" phone number and place the party in the conference room. You will notice that like the code in step #1 we employ the '/getconf' route. The Twilio server will call this URL to get the TwiML that defines how it should process the call.

```
@app.route('/getconf', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def getconf():
 resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
 conf_room = request.values.get('Conference')

 resp.dial().conference(conf_room)
 return str(resp)
```

We also defined a '/callback' route that is called upon call completion (hangup) or failure of caller #2 or #3. Since answering Step 1 I have enhanced the way this callback works. My goal is that when all 'To' parties hang up, leaving only the original caller in the conference room, the call should hangup for the original caller. Otherwise, the From caller will just be left in the conference room listening to music. This is not what is expected.

Therefore I implemented the following callback code:

```
@app.route('/callback', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def callback():
  account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
  auth_token = os.environ.get("AUTH_TOKEN", AUTH_TOKEN)

  callback_status = request.values.get('CallStatus')
  conf_room = request.values.get('Conference')

  client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
  conferences = client.conferences.list(friendly_name=conf_room, status = "in-progress")
  if (len(conferences) > 0):
    conference = conferences[0]
    participants = client.participants(conference.sid).list()
    if len(participants) == 1:
      participant = participants[0]
      call = client.calls.hangup(participant.call_sid)

  return str("200")
```

When called, this code grabs the conference room by name, then grabs the list of participants in the conference room. If there is only one participant remaining then it hangs up on the last participant.

The final step is making the call from your iOS code. This is quite simple, you do not need to use the Twilio client libraries for this call, you simply make an http GET request passing in From, To and the Conference room name as parameters. Like this:

```
http:/yourpythonserver.com/add_to_conference?To=1234567890&From=0987654321&Conference=MyConference
```

This will activate the entire process and party #3 will be placed in the conference room!